# Bibliography subdivision for PhD thesis using chapterbib

Tags: bibliographies

I have a PhD thesis that is made of 2 parts. Parts 1 is the main documents with chapters and I need a whole bibliography at the end of this part.
Part 2 has some articles and I need a bibliography at the end of each article so I put `\bibliographystyle{plain}`followed by `\bibliography{article/article.bib}` at the end of each article.tex. Here is the code:

```
\usepackage[]{chapterbib}
\begin{document}
\part{First} 
\include{Chap1/Chap1}
\include{Chap2/Chap2}
\include{Chap3/Chap3}
\include{...}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{main/main.bib}

\part{Second}
\include{article1/article1}
\include{article2/article2}
```

The problem is that it will compile the right way the second part, but for the first I have a bibliography after the whole part but the respective citation are (??). 
I tried to add `\bibliographystyle{plain}`followed by `\bibliography{chapter/chapter.bib}` at the end of each chapter. This give me right citation but it also add a bibliography after each chapter (I only want a bibliography at the end of the all chapters).

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I've used successfully the package `bibunits`. You can put bibliographies at each chapter, and even a compendium of the end of your manuscritp. The manual is very self-contained, `texdoc bibunits`. Moreover, it compiles automaticaly al the bibtex if you use `latexmk`

Comment: Thanks @Dox , I will check `bibunits` docs

Comment: The problem I found is that bu.aux files have a `\bibdata{main}` that refer to `main.tex` files and not to the `file.bib`that i have inserted with the command `\putbib{file.bib}`

Comment: Sorry is my error as `\putbib[file.bib]` must have `[ ]`and not `{ }`.

Comment: @Dox and lorenzo, if you need ´hyperref´, then the solution fails with ´bibunits´. Any ideas to solve the problem?

Comment: I would suggest using `biblatex` here.

Comment: Is there any news here?