# Split bibliography by parts

Tags: bibliographies

(*[almost related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/243348/14757)*)

I have a single `.bib` file. My document has two parts and I'd like to print at end of each part the bibliography with **only the items cited in that part**. Of course, there could be intersection if an item was cited in both parts.

No preferences, could be `bibtex`, `biblatex` or something extra.

**MWE**

```
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{faa,
  title={Faa Something important},
  author={Faa Big Guy and Another Big Guy},
  journal={Prestigious Journal},
  volume={47},
  number={7},
  pages={966--978},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Institute}
}
@article{foo,
  title={Foo Something important},
  author={Foo Big Guy and Another Big Guy},
  journal={Prestigious Journal},
  volume={47},
  number={7},
  pages={966--978},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Institute}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\part{Faa}
\cite{faa}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}

\part{Foo}
\cite{foo}

%% I tried to insert twice, but got an error
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` defines a `refsection` environment.  See § 3.7.4, Bibliography Sections, pp. 88-89 in the documentation.

Comment: So, if I well understood, I should insert the whole `\part{}...` within `refsection`, right?

Comment: Actually, I've never used it, but that 's the way I understand it.

Answer (score 2):

[Bernard](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/38908/bernard) already mentions `refsection`s in his answer.

Note that `biblatex` has an option called `refsection`, that can be used to automatically start a new `refsection` at certain section commands. For example `refsection=part` will create a new `refsection` for each `\part`. No additional code is required.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, refsection=part]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\part{One}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography

\part{Two}
\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Parts with refsections]

You can start a new `refsection` that will go on until the next `refsection` with

```
\newrefsection
```

If you want finer control over `refsection`s and their end, you can use the environment form.

```
\begin{refsection}

\end{refsection}
```

Note that `refsection`s can't be nested and that everything outside a particular `refsection` happens in section 0.

`refsection`s keep their contents completely separate and independent from each other. That means that the same entry could end up with different citation labels in each section or vice versa, i.e. two different entries get the same label.

If that is not desired (or you are looking for a way to create an overall bibliography at the end), you may want to look at `refsegment`s. `refsegment`s essentially just mark an entry as cited in a particular segment of your document. Again, there is an option called `refsegment` that starts a new `refsegment` for each sectioning command of a specific type.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, refsegment=part]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\part{One}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]

\part{Two}
\cite{sigfridsson,nussbaum,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment]

\printbibliography[title=Overall \bibname]
\end{document}
```

[image: Parts with refsegments]

Like `refsection`, `refsegment`s can be started with

```
\newrefsegment
```

or can be used as environment

```
\begin{refsegment}

\end{refsegment}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this very clear explanation.